# How to remove/costomize the index page of R-manuals, when generating r-packages?

Tags: r, package, manual

The command R CMD CHECK also outputs a manual of the generated R package. This manual includes an index page on the last page of the manual that shows two additional repeating sections (see below). Do you know how to customise or remove this index page in the manual when generating an r-package?

∗Topic \textasciitildekwd1

∗Topic \textasciitildekwd2

Comment: As far as I know, without changing the source code, not easily.

Comment: What exactly means source code in this context? Usually everything regarding the manual can be changed in the .Rd files or the description file, but I cannot find any manipulation of this index page there. Do you mean one needs to hack the way R checks its packages and produces the manual? What also confuses me is, that about a half year ago this index page was not included in the manual when generating packages, so probably it has something to do with an R update?

Comment: I meant the R source code.